# Job offer from 2 companies in the same building

Tags: job-search, job-offer, job-change, united-kingdom, qualification

So for the past two years, I have been working part time for a company whilst at college and now I’m about to enter my last year which could govern me signing a full time contract or leaving. As currently there is no contract ( more like an paid internship ) I am not bound to return come, summer next year.

This year whilst I was at college full time, the company I work for, call them ‘ Company A’ rented out the second floor of their two story building due to a reduction in workforce. When I returned this year July, there is a company who also do similar work to ‘Company A’. Technically, in education terms I am overqualified for company A, but the tenants of the second floor ( Company B) on paper I would be better suited and in the long term would be a more rewarding career.

Here the dilemma starts, as I was in the shared kitchen, I strike a conversation with the boss of company B and we begin conversing, I explained that I’m a student and just preforming an internship for experience. To cut the story short at the end he gives me his card and requests my CV. 
I was debating not doing it as at the moment I am employed by company A till October. But anyway in my free time I did. And now company B has offered me a position upon me qualifying. Company A has also offered me a position.

I know the people at Company A well and I feel like I am bound in more of a respectful way to the boss of A, but company B has also taken interest to me. I do not want this situation to cause animosity between the companies by my current boss having issues with the tenants (company B) ‘taking employees’.

Options:

- Work for company A and possibly feel regret due to the over qualification yet, progress quicker.
- Work for company B but possibly loose a good working relationship with company A.
- Or leave both and search elsewhere.

What other options are available?

Comment: Depending on your industry you may need to be careful of a Non-compete Claus in your contract.

Comment: @JCrosby within engineering say Company A do External Electrical consultancy and design and manufacture of PCBs, I am an electronic engineer, so not technically in the same industry...

Comment: Are any interns ever given non-competes? That would seem highly strange.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. You're not an employee, you're an intern. Company B can't be accused of "taking employees" if you're not an employee.
2. Do what you feel is best for you and what feels the most "right" to you.
3. If there's any animosity, it has nothing to do with you. Don't let the actions, words, feelings of others dictate your career path.
4. The only thing you need be concerned with is if there's some legal impediment to your taking the job of your choice. As an intern, it's doubtful that any such legal impediment exists.

Comment: Even if there was animosity I'd wager it would be because they're competing businesses not because they're poaching employees off each other.  In any case they'll get over it.

Comment: Also, the current company doesn't own you and you have no obligations to stay.

Comment: **Don't let the actions, words, feelings of others dictate your career path.** - this is the most important advice, what you make of your career is up to you.